# Setting panel height with content that does not fill the panel completely

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a two panels which have to be the same height. The code for the panels is below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1"  GroupingText="Material" CssClass="material" 
                runat="server" >

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"   runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Plastics</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Enabled="false">Glass</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

             </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2"  GroupingText="Material" CssClass="design" 
                runat="server" >

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"   runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem >SV</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem ">Bifocal</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem >Varifocal</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem >Intermediate</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

             </asp:Panel>
```

I have a styled these two panels with the css below:

```
.material{display:inline-block; float:left;max-height:200px;width:90px;overflow:hidden;}
.design {display:inline-block; float:left;max-height:200px;width:210px;overflow:hidden;}
```

Notice I tried making the height same. However since panel1 has little content, the border of the panel does go all the way to height 200px. How can I have same height even when content does not fill the panel completely.

Comment: Use height instead of max-height?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have but still no change.

Comment: It would help if you would paste the generated HTML code here or on http://jsfiddle.net/. Meantime try setting the display to block instead of inline-block

Answer (score 1):

The Panel in asp.net when rendered in HTML doesn't get rendered as a panel as panel is not a valid html tag. 
you could wrap div inside of the panel and provide styling to the div.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1"  GroupingText="Material" CssClass="material" 
            runat="server" >
            <div class="material">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"   runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Plastics</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Enabled="false">Glass</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
         </asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2"  GroupingText="Material" CssClass="design" 
            runat="server" >
            <div class="design">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"   runat="server" >
            <asp:ListItem >SV</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem ">Bifocal</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem >Varifocal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem >Intermediate</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
         </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that later. I have already got the solution and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the max-height in yours css and add this code:

```
fieldset {height:200px}
```